# How to use base64 command with CURL?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

If I attempt to base64 encode a font file and output the contents to a text file like so:

```
base64 myfont.woff2 > output.txt
```

It works great given that the font is stored locally. However if I try to curl the font from a web url and base64 the output it results in a bunch of gibberish being saved to the file, for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr=(
    "https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v14/K88pR3goAWT7BTt32Z01mxJtnKITppOI_IvcXXDNrsc.woff2"
)

for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    content="$(curl -s "$i")"
    echo base64 "$content" > output.txt
done
```

How to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pipe `curl` output to `base64`:

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
   curl -s "$i" | base64
done > output.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

The `base64` command is expecting the text to be decoded as input, not as an argument. You can either pipe curl to it directly:

```
curl -s "$url" | base64
```

or, once you've captured the curl results in a variable as in your original code, use a here-string:

```
base64 <<<"$content"
```